# Custom window for CHM help project

Tags: wpf, chm

We're developing in WPF and are using custom borderless windows like the new Office 2013 windows. Now we are creating CHM help using RoboHelp.

I'd like to know if there's a way to launch a CHM file, but somehow hook into it so that it loads in a custom window that I specify, rather than the default window. Even better would be some kind of CHM display control that could be embedded in a WPF window, analogous to the way you can embed an HTML browser control in a WPF window. That way I could compile the CHM content with RoboHelp, but display it in our own custom borderless window that's part of our application.

Answer (score 0):

CHM is no longer supported by MS since Vista, so you might want to consider using RoboHelp to generate Webhelp instead, and display that in a browser control as you described.  Webhelp also supports context sensitivity via the URL, if that is needed.

Comment: The problem with that is you have to have a server to run the web-help.  That, or you have to set up the entire hierarchy on your file system as opposed to a single file. Plus, using a web browser control in WPF causes AirSpace issues.  And as for other formats, don't even get me started about AirHelp!  CHM really is preferrable for off-line help and RoboHelp still creates CHM files just fine.  (They may be based on HTMLHelp from what I understand.)  I'm with this person... how can we display help in our app and not in an external window.

Comment: What's the problem with installing the "entire hierarchy" with your app?  You don't have to copy them manually; that's what installers are for :)
You are right though, CMH is HMTLHelp zipped together.

Comment: One word... versioning.  That's what.  When it's a single file, you can check it against its version number to make sure the right file goes with the right version of the app.  This is especially true in development and testing.  Also, managing an entire folder of files is just more cumbersome.  Plus, as I already pointed out, you run into airspace issues when using a web browser control in a WPF app.

Comment: I put version tracking in the default topic :-p